# How to deserialize [[doubles], [ints]] array with C# MsgPack?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, deserialization, msgpack

So msgpack-c provides me with [objects as arrays](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/master/example/cpp03/custom.cpp).  Say I serialized a a C++ message alike this:

```
template <class T>
        struct Message {
            std::vector<T> data;
            std::vector<int> shape; 
            MSGPACK_DEFINE(data, shape);
        };
```

and had `T == double`.

If deserialised to json in C++ it would have internals like `[[1.23,3.01,44.02,33],[2,2]]`.

Now I want to deserialize it in [C# with MessagePack-CSharp](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp). If I try to turn it into json string I get an empty string, when I try

```
var msg = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<double>>>(e.RawData);
```

I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: code is invalid. code:0
>   format:positive fixint   at
>   MessagePack.Decoders.InvalidArrayHeader.Read (System.Byte[] bytes,
>   Int32 offset, System.Int32& readSize) [0x0001b] in
>   MessagePack/MessagePackBinary.cs:3543

same happens when I try:

```
 [MessagePackObject]
    public class Msg {
        [Key(0)]
        public List<double> data;
            [Key(1)]
        public List<int> shape;
    }
```

So how to deserialize `[[doubles], [ints]]` array in C# MessagePack-CSharp?

Answer (score 1):

```
[MessagePackObject]
public class Msg
{
    [Key(0)]
    public List<double> data;
    [Key(1)]
    public List<int> shape;
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(new Msg()
        {
            data = new List<double> { 1.23, 3.01, 44.02, 33 },
            shape = new List<int>() { 2, 2 }
        });
        var msg = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<Msg>(bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(MessagePackSerializer.ToJson(msg));
    }
}
```

should do the work and produces the output [[1.23,3.01,44.02,33],[2,2]]

Comment: I get same exception

Comment: Please check your byte stream e.RawData. The length should be 41 bytes. Perhaps the binary format of c++ and c# version are different, because you got an InvalidArrayHeader exception (according the sources).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.